# Is there a way to see how much time remains on a timed process?

Tags: bash, unix, process

Is there a way to determine (in bash) how much time is remaining on a process that is running for a specified time?

For example, some time after executing

```
caffeinate -s -t 8000 &
```

is there a command or technique for determining when my system will be allowed to sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash won't know that `caffeinate` has a timer attached to it; for all it knows, `-t` refers to the number of times you'll place an Amazon order of Red Bull before the process exits five minutes later.

If you know this, however, you can detect when the command was started and do the math yourself.

```
$ sleep 45 &
[1] 16065

$ ps -o cmd,etime
CMD                             ELAPSED
sleep 45                          00:03
ps -o cmd,etime                   00:00
/bin/bash                    6-21:11:11
```

On OS X, this will be `ps -o command,etime`; see the [FreeBSD `ps` man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)) or [Linux `ps` docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps) for details and other switches/options.